# Why does clicking path from ESLint not open file at 274:35?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

```
$ npm run lint
/Users/john/test/src/index.ts
  274:35  warning  'event' is defined but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

Comment: Is that in the Problems view? Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks for helping out @wjandrea… terminal view. Can’t share screenshot for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a different [formatter](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/formatters/) to have the problems printed in a way that lets you open the respective lines by clicking on a link in the terminal.

This should work out of the box:

```
npx run lint -- --format=visualstudio
```

and print

```
/Users/john/test/src/index.ts(274,35): warning @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars : 'event' is defined but never used
```

Or this one:

```
npx run lint -- --format=unix
```

which prints

```
/Users/john/test/src/index.ts:274:35: 'event' is defined but never used [Warning/@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars]
```

To avoid specifying the formatter manually every time, you could add them directly to the `"lint"` script defined in the file package.json, e.g.:

```
   "scripts": {
     ...
     "lint": "eslint . --format=visualstudio",
     ...
   },
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! What worked for me is adding following to `package.json` scripts. `"lint": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx --format=visualstudio ."`.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal isn't smart enough to do that. For it to hyperlink straight to a location in a file, the path would have to be *immediately followed* by a colon and the location, i.e. `/Users/john/test/src/index.ts:274:35`.

Instead, you might consider installing a plugin, or configuring an existing one, to show lint results in the **Problems** view. VSCode will then link straight to the location. I don't have any recommendations since I don't work in TypeScript myself, but FWIW, the Python extension can do that, for example with the Pylama linter enabled.

Comment: Interesting… would you happen to know why that path format was not used by ESLint or how one can enable it?

Comment: @sunknudsen I don't know; I would assume it just wasn't a design consideration, but also there are lots of terminals that don't do hyperlinks, and if there were multiple problems in one file, it'd require repeating the path for each one -- very verbose.